# How can I execute some Javascript after all ASP.NET startup scripts have been executed?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page with a variety of client-side controls being initialized via `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`. I have another script that I need to ensure runs only after all of the registered startup scripts have executed, without having control over the order they're registered in or their contents.

Is there any way I can make my script execute only after the start up scripts have been run?

Comment: Make the StartUp script to receive a callback function (the other script) and place the call for that function in a proper place.

Comment: That's not possible, I don't have control over or even know what the other start up scripts are.

Answer (score 0):

All scripts registered with [RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(v=vs.110).aspx) are rendered right before the closing `</form>` tag. To ensure that a particular `<script>` block runs after them, just add it to the .aspx file after that tag.